# Unity [C#] Setting a RectTransfrom value to 0 don't set it to 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do a scoreboard when you press tab. There is multiple teams so I did different pages for the scoreboard.

[image]

tab is a canvas where all the scoreboard will be (the scoreboards are created with panel objects)

When I run this code

```
tab_page = tab_page + value; //tab_page is the page where I am in the scoreboard (0 is the first page and value is -1 or 1 depending in which way you want to travel the scoreboard)
Vector3 pos = new Vector3(tab_page * Screen.width, tab.transform.position.y, tab.transform.position.z);
Debug.Log(pos.x);
tab.transform.position = pos;
```

The Debug.Log print me 1102 but the position of the RectTransform is set to 551 -551 and I don't know why !

[image]

So if someone has a clue about this I thank you already.

Answer (score 0):

The information that appears in the inspector is relative to the anchor that you are using.